# Get one object with each unique property-value

Tags: javascript

I have an array with several objects. I want to get the **first object** (the order is significant) with each unique value of `ref`:

```
var data = [
    { id: "asghalk", etc: "Hello World", ref: "ad23f1" },
    { id: "glfdknd", etc: "Testing, 12", ref: "912b12" },
    { id: "lka09go", etc: "Some String", ref: "ad23f1" },
    { id: "klghame", etc: "Hello World", ref: "124e12" },
    { id: "glkahma", etc: "Hello World", ref: "124e12" }
];
```

From this, I want:

```
var result = [
    { id: "asghalk", etc: "Hello World", ref: "ad23f1" },
    { id: "glfdknd", etc: "Testing, 12", ref: "912b12" },
    { id: "klghame", etc: "Hello World", ref: "124e12" },
]
```

(Only the objects with a new `ref` are kept.) Any proposals (with any dependencies) are welcome.

Comment: What decides which object to take when an identical `ref` value is found? How did you decide that `klghame` should be returned from `124e12` instead of `klghame`?

Comment: The OP says he wants the first object for each ref, so I assume klghame is selected as it's the first entry in the array.

Comment: I thought this was clear, but emphasized it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 _.uniq(data,'ref');
```

I used here loadash js library method uniq,through this you can get objects which contains uniq refs

Answer (score 2):

The following code finds the first record in the array for each unique value of 'ref':

```
var data = [
    { id: "asghalk", etc: "Hello World", ref: "ad23f1" },
    { id: "glfdknd", etc: "Testing, 12", ref: "912b12" },
    { id: "lka09go", etc: "Some String", ref: "ad23f1" },
    { id: "klghame", etc: "Hello World", ref: "124e12" },
    { id: "glkahma", etc: "Hello World", ref: "124e12" }
];

var result = [];
var found = {};
for (idx = 0; idx < data.length; idx++) {
    if (!found[data[idx].ref]) {
        found[data[idx].ref] = true;
        result.push(data[idx]);
    }
}
```

The code maintains a table of refs that have already been found, and only adds objects to the result array if the  ref hasn't already been seen.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using an empty js object like a dictionary/map

```
<html>
    <script>
        var data = [
            { id: "asghalk", etc: "Hello World", ref: "ad23f1" },
            { id: "glfdknd", etc: "Testing, 12", ref: "912b12" },
            { id: "lka09go", etc: "Some String", ref: "ad23f1" },
            { id: "klghame", etc: "Hello World", ref: "124e12" },
            { id: "glkahma", etc: "Hello World", ref: "124e12" }
        ];

        var result = [];
        var map = {};

        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
            map[ data[i].ref ] = data[i];
        }

        for(var item in map){
            //document.write("[item]"+item + "<br>");
            result.push(map[item]);
        }

        for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++){
            document.write(JSON.stringify(result[i]) + "<br>");
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: I can see you just edited this. Now the result array is empty. Before your edit you returned the *last* objects matching, not the first.

Comment: I was removing a debugging line (document.write) ... the StackOverflow editor isn't as friendly to use as I expected :(

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = [
    { id: "asghalk", etc: "Hello World", ref: "ad23f1" },
    { id: "glfdknd", etc: "Testing, 12", ref: "912b12" },
    { id: "lka09go", etc: "Some String", ref: "ad23f1" },
    { id: "klghame", etc: "Hello World", ref: "124e12" },
    { id: "glkahma", etc: "Hello World", ref: "124e12" }
];
result = new Array();
for(i=0;i<data.length;++i){
  var descriptor=Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(data[i], "ref");
    a=false;
    while(a!=true){
      for(j=i;j<data.length;++j)
       if(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(data[i], "ref").value==Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(data[j], "ref").value){
           result.push(data[i]);
           a=true; break;
       }
    }
}
```